# MATLAB : how to solve coupled differential equations dependend on data stored in arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, differential-equations

I want to solve a system of two ordinary differential equations in MATLAB.
The parameters of the ODEs depend on measured data stored in two arrays, `F` and `T`.

When I run the program, I always get the error shown below. I am sure it has something to do with the arrays, because when I use single numbers for `F` and `T` (e.g. `F = 60`; `T = 30`;) the program works fine.

```
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
 
Error in dynamics (line 46)
ddyn(1) = k1*F(t) + v_b(t) - k_1*dyn(1) - v_a(t);

Error in ode23 (line 256)
f(:,2) = feval(odeFcn,t+h*A(1),y+f*hB(:,1),odeArgs{:});

Error in main (line 33)
[t,sol] = ode23(@dynamics , (1:1:3000),[0 0]);
```

Here is the code I use for the main function and the ODE system:

Main function:

```
[t,sol] = ode45(@dynamics , (1:1:3000),[0 0]);
```

ODE system:

```
function [ddyn] = dynamics(t,dyn)

% constant numbers
k1 = 10^-2; k_1 = 8* 10^-3; k2 = 10^-2; k_2 = 4*10^-3; 
V_max_a = 1.6; V_max_b = 3.5;    
K_M_a = 1.5*10^-3; K_M_b = 2*10^-3;       
K_a_F = 9.4*10^5; K_a_T = 3.9*10; K_b_F = 1.3*10^4; K_b_T = 1.2*10^-10;
r_a_F = 4.3*10^7; r_a_T = 4.2*10^9; r_b_F = 6.9*10^-7; r_b_T = 6.2*10^-9;    

%arrays with data e.g. 
F = 1:3000;
T = 1:3000;

% program works if I use numbers, e.g.: 
%F = 60; T = 30; 


ddyn = zeros(2,1);

R_a_F = (K_a_F + r_a_F* F)/(K_a_F + r_a_F);   
R_a_T = (K_a_T + r_a_T* T)/(K_a_T + r_a_T);
R_b_F = (K_b_F + r_b_F* F)/(K_b_F + r_b_F);
R_b_T = (K_b_T + r_b_T* T)/(K_b_T + r_b_T);

 v_a = (V_max_a*dyn(1))/(K_M_a + dyn(1))*R_a_F .*R_a_T;
 v_b = (V_max_b*dyn(2))/(K_M_b + dyn(2))*R_b_F .*R_b_T;



ddyn(1) = k1*F(t) + v_b(t) - k_1*dyn(1) - v_a(t);
ddyn(2) = k2*T(t) + v_a(t) - k_2*dyn(2) - v_b(t);
```

Comment: You are not showing the error, only the line. Still, there is a single solution er (F,T) pair, are you expecting to solve for 9000000 cases in one go???

Comment: Thx @Ander Biguri I completed the error message. I have never solved a ODE in matlab before so I don't really know what to do. Maybe it would work if F and T were given as functions?

Answer (score 2):

All of the functions in the Matlab [ODE suite](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ordinary-differential-equations.html), including [`ode45`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html), assume `t` *to be continuous* and use a dynamic time-step to achieve a certain level of accuracy.<sup>1</sup>  As such, you cannot assume `t` to be an integer and should never be used as an index as you are doing with `F(t)`.  To quote from [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html#inputarg_tspan):

> If `tspan` contains more than two elements `[t0,t1,t2,...,tf]`, then the solver returns the solution evaluated at the given points. This does not affect the internal steps that the solver uses to traverse from `tspan(1)` to `tspan(end)`. Thus, the solver does not necessarily step precisely to each point specified in `tspan`.

Therefore, assuming `F` and `T` are continuous functions in time, I'd recommend making a function that performs interpolation in time, more than likely via [`interp1`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html), and pass that function to your ODE function through [parametrization](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html#bu3uhuk).  For example:

```
tspan = 1:3000;
Ffun  = @(t) interp1(tspan,F,t); % Default is linear
[t,sol] = ode45(@(t,dyn) dynamics(t,dyn,Ffun) , tspan , [0 0]);
```

That's just an example but should, hopefully, be serviceable.

---

<sup>1</sup> In particular, `ode45` uses the [Dormand-Prince (4,5)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dormand%E2%80%93Prince_method) Runkge-Kutta pair for its time integration; in short, the function compares a fourth order and fifth order solution to decide if the result from the current time-step is good enough or if it should be reduced.

Comment: Thank you, @TroyHaskin. I now used interpolation but I now get this error: Undefined operator ' * ' for input arguments of type 'function_handle'.  Do I have to use something like  ' .* '  , if I want to multiply functions?

Comment: @maxE Where is this function handle coming from?  If you're talking about `Ffun`, you need to pass `t` to it within `dynamics` since `Ffun` is now a function. Just like `F(t)`, but now it will work since `Ffun` is actually a function.

Comment: now it seems to work. May I ask you one more question? If I want to handle to the ODE which I want to solve, two functions F,T , would this be the correct syntax:  [t,sol] = ode45(@(t,dyn) dynamics(t,dyn,F,T) , (1:3000) , [0 0])  ?

Comment: @maxE Yep.  As long as `dynamics` accepts that many arguments, it should work fine.